# python two dictionaries into one? mixed up keys and values

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, key

I've got two dictionaries, d1, and d2 for each entry (a, b) in d1, if a is not a key of d2  then add (a,b) to the new dictionary for each entry (a, b) in d2, if a is not a key of d1 (i.e., not a in d1) then add (a,b) to the new dictionary  Example if d1 is {2:3, 8:19, 6:4, 5:12} and d2 is {2:5, 4:3, 3:9}, then the new dictionary should be {8:19, 6:4, 5:12, 4:3, 3:9}. Here's my code thus far.

```
d3 = {}
for i in d1.items():
    if i[1] not  in d2.keys():
        d3[i[0]] = d2[i[1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Python 2.7, you can take key views of each dict, do a symmetric difference, and pick the value for each key from the dict that had that key:

```
result = {key: d1[key] if key in d1 else d2[key]
          for key in d1.viewkeys() ^ d2.viewkeys()}
```

In Python 3.x, it's pretty much the same, except `viewkeys` is just `keys`:

```
result = {key: d1[key] if key in d1 else d2[key]
          for key in d1.keys() ^ d2.keys()}
```

Before 2.7, there were no dict views or dict comprehensions, but you can just use `set`s and the `dict` constructor with a generator expression:

```
result = dict((key, d1[key] if key in d1 else d2[key])
              for key in set(d1).symmetric_difference(d2))
```

Comment: `set(d1).symmetric_difference(s2)` will do it - but anyway before 2.7 there were no dict-comp's either ;)

Comment: @JonClements: Right. I was actually just about to check when those went in; somehow I thought it was 2.6.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> d1={2:3, 8:19, 6:4, 5:12}
>>> d2={2:5, 4:3, 3:9}
>>> d12 = {k:v for k,v in d1.items() if k not in d2}
>>> d21 = {k:v for k,v in d2.items() if k not in d1}
>>> answer = {k:v for k,v in itertools.chain(d12.items(), d21.items())}
>>> answer
{8: 19, 3: 9, 4: 3, 5: 12, 6: 4}
```

Hope this helps